# Make tool tip wrap text

Tags: leaflet

I can't figure out how to wrap the text on the leaflet tooltip. I dont want to display the marker so its hidden, but i want to the text to wrap the text in the tooltip if possible

```
.myTooltip {
  background: green;
  border: 2px solid cyan
}

.leaflet-tooltip-left.myTooltip::before {
  border-left-color: cyan;
}
.leaflet-tooltip-right.myTooltip::before {
  border-right-color: red;
}
```

then adding to the map, i've change the properties of the no wrap but doens't seem to effect anything. Also, for some reason the background color doens't seem to be changing, but thats a different questions

```
var marker = L.marker(new L.LatLng(item.Latitude, item.Longitude), { opacity: 0 }); //can be set to zero
                    marker.bindTooltip(item.Text, { permanent: true, noWrap: true, className: "myTooltip", offset: [0, 0] });
                    marker.addTo(mymap);
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to override `white-space` property of `leaflet-tooltip` class. Additionally, you may set the `width` of the tooltip as well.

Just add this after your `leaflet.css` file

```css
.leaflet-tooltip{
    width: 100px;
    white-space: normal;
}
```

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/z9c5eccq/) is a working example